# Convert SQL columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, rows

I would like to split one records columns into multiple rows.

If I have a SQL statement like the following:

```
SELECT 1,2,3
```

Result:

```
1 | 2 | 3
```

How do I convert that to the following result?

```
1
2
3
```

I am currently using MS SQL 2008.

Comment: Is this really what you want to do?  If not you should post something more realistic.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION
SELECT 3
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it without modifying to original SELECT statement? ie SELECT converttorow(SELECT 1,2,3)

Comment: @ChrisCrous: you can create your function or storedprocedure where you just pass these comma separated values and there you can put your t-sql logic to generate such output..

Comment: Check [Convert Comma Separated Values into Rows](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1043869-149-1.aspx#bm1043876) and with oracle [Convert comma separated string in rows](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2320358).. [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic968028-338-1.aspx#bm968044)  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator).. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the comments above:

- If you want to convert columns into rows, you will need to use the
  T-SQL [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) clause.

  If you want to split a single column that contains comma separated
  values, you will need to create a Function ([example here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic968028-338-1.aspx#bm968044))