# Select some columns and show column names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following table `daysTurns`:

[image: Table]

How can I get a result like this?

```
date        turn      mail
2017-04-03  turn11    luis@geen.com
2017-04-03  turn12    luis@geen.com
2017-04-03  turn13    luis@geen.com
2017-04-03  turn21    luis@geen.com
2017-04-03  turn21    luis@geen.com
2017-04-03  turn21    luis@geen.com
2017-04-04  turn11    luis@geen.com
2017-04-04  turn12    luis@geen.com
2017-04-04  turn13    luis@geen.com
2017-04-04  turn21    luis@geen.com
2017-04-04  turn22    luis@geen.com
2017-04-04  turn23    luis@geen.com
```

I assume I would need a query like `SELECT * FROM daysTurns`.

And this is the expected OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain in a sentence what you are trying to select? And maybe the structure of the tables you think might need to be involved.

Comment: How many fields like 'turn%' do you have?

Comment: this is a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513820/convert-sql-columns-to-rows

Comment: and of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко 6 columns

Comment: @maSTArHiAn this is for SQLServer, my question is for Mysql.

Comment: @moondaisy as you can see on the table, there's 6 turns per day. I need to show a summary of the assigned turns for every user, like the output example.

Comment: Check my code in answer.

Comment: true that @LuisGarcía but the solution is no different to mysql for this particular issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have only 6 columns which look like a 'turn__', then Try to do this:

```
SELECT date, 'turn11' as turn, mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn11 is not null and turn11 <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'turn12' as turn, mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn12 is not null and turn12 <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'turn13' as turn, mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn13 is not null and turn13 <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'turn21' as turn, mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn21 is not null and turn21 <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'turn22' as turn, mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn22 is not null and turn22 <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'turn23' as turn, mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn23 is not null and turn23 <> ''
```

Comment: Thank you! Based on your response i can build the correct one:

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The solution query:

```
SET @mail = 'the_mail_that_i_need';

SELECT date, 'turn11' as turn, turn11 as mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn11 = @mail 
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'turn12' as turn, turn12 as mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn12 = @mail
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'turn13' as turn, turn13 as mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn13 = @mail
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'turn21' as turn, turn21 as mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn21 = @mail
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'turn22' as turn, turn22 as mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn22 = @mail
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'turn23' as turn, turn23 as mail FROM daysTurns
WHERE turn23 = @mail
ORDER BY date ASC
```