# Column to comma separated value in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

It's been asked and answered for SQL ([Convert multiple rows into one with comma as separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator)), would any of the approaches mentioned work in Hive, e.g. to go from this:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
| a    | 1    |
| a    | 5    |
| a    | 6    |
| b    | 2    |
| b    | 6    |
+------+------+
```

to this:

```
+------+-------+
| Col1 | Col2  |
+------+-------+
| a    | 1,5,6 |
| b    | 2,6   |
+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The aggregator function `collect_set` can achieve what you are trying to get. [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) is the documentation. So you can write a query like:

```
SELECT Col1, collect_set(Col2)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Col1;
```

However, there is one striking difference between MySQL's `GROUP BY` and Hive's `collect_set` that while `GROUP_CONCAT` also retains duplicates in the resulting array, `collect_set` removes the duplicates occuring in the array. In the example shown by you there are no repeating group values for `Col2` so you can go ahead and use it.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT can eliminate duplicates by using distinct.
GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT expression
    ORDER BY expression
    SEPARATOR sep
);

Answer (score 8):

And there is `collect_list` that will take full list (with duplicates).

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```sql
SELECT Col1, concat_ws(',', collect_set(Col2)) as col2
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Col1;
```

[apache.org documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions)