# Aggregating strings with hortonworks hadoop hive

Tags: string, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to flatten a security table to make a single row per country. I am using Hive as the execution engine currently in hortonworks if this makes a difference to the SQL required.

An example of what im trying to achieve is below.

```
(country, Name)
(US, 'Matt'),
(US, 'Rocks'),
(GB, 'Stylus'),
(FR, 'Foo'),
(FR, 'Bar'),
(FR, 'Baz')
```

The query result I am after :

```
Country Name
----------- ------------------------------
GB           Stylus
FR           Bar, Baz, Foo
US           Matt, Rocks
```

I am really lost as to where to start.  Does anyone know? I found some syntax on another thread that work fine in MSSQL but not here in hortonworks.

[Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Hadoop, but following [Column to comma separated value in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705398/column-to-comma-separated-value-in-hive) you can make this:

```
SELECT country, collect_set(Name)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY country;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `collect_set` for string aggregation into array and `concat_ws` to convert array to the comma separated string

```
select country, concat_ws(',', collect_set(Name)) 
   from table
 group by country
```