# Convert set of rows to column with list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have requirement where I need to convert list of rows into single column value.

Ex:

```
ID           Value
1            v1
1            v2
1            v3
2            v4
2            v5
2            v6
2            v7 
and so on..
```

Need to convert as

```
ID         New Value
1          v1,v2,v3
2          v4,v5,v6,v7
```

Please let me know how I can write query in SQL server.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
  STUFF((SELECT ',' + Value
         FROM Table T
         WHERE T.ID = ID
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS [New Value]
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
```

I got it from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785923/215752

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - If such was the case then I would have put a cast to a varchar in my example of course.  Please point out more things that would be wrong if it was a different question.