# SQL how to do a pivot of one column regardless of the data

Tags: sql

I basically need to change multiple rows into one row

So basically i have the follow results

```
myId  
apple  
bear  
tiger
```

and I want to change this into `apple`|`bear`|`tiger`   but how can I do these with a pivot not knowing what the data result is going to be?  I tried

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP (3) myId FROM myTable) src PIVOT (max (myId ) FOR myId IN ([1], [2], [3])) piv;`

but the data isnt [1], [2], [3]

Comment: The only way to do this is with dynamic sql.  what platform are you using?

Comment: What @Hogan said.  If you don't know the values ahead of time you can't write a `PIVOT` statement.  Dynamic SQL is the only way.

Comment: @yuck well what would you suggest, i'm trying to just select the top 3 rows of a column and get them into 1 row

Comment: Are you trying to make apple/bear/tiger into field names, or just as data in known fields?

Comment: @Mike - if using sql server, this might work (replace `,` with `|`) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator/1785923#1785923

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson what i want to do is select the top 3 rows from column x and make it into 3 columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use ROW_NUMBER() to number the rows, and use a manual pivot to convert them into fields;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT myId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myId) rn FROM mytable
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN myId END) field1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN myId END) field2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=3 THEN myId END) field3
FROM cte;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8a72/2).

Comment: @Yuck Yes, I assumed that from the `TOP 3 myId`, of course I may have missed some alternative :)

Comment: Why would this work, he says he does not know the field names before hand -- I guess if he does not mind the generic fieldX then it is OK

Comment: @Hogan My mistake. I though that CTE syntax and the `ROW_NUMBER` function were specific to SQL Server.

Comment: @Yuck - nope... they are both part of the SQL standard.  99 and 2002 I believe.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Dynamic SQL to construct all the distinct possible values to be used in `PIVOT`

In your case you can fetch the TOP 3 values and construct the column list and use PIVOT.

This [Dynamic Column PIVOT article](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/) explains how to do it.

In the first select query, we are getting data values for the top 3 myid values and constructing the column list
Using this @cols variable inside the dynamic `PIVOT` query.
You need to add order by on appropriate column.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT 
                                '],[' + t1.data
                        FROM    Table1 AS t1
                        JOIN ( Select TOP 3 myId from Table1) T
                        on t1.myId = T.myId
                        ORDER BY '],[' + t1.data
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @query = N'SELECT myId, '+
@cols +'
FROM
(SELECT t1.myId , t1.data 
        FROM Table1 
        JOIN ( Select TOP 3 myId from Table1) T
        on t1.myId = T.myId
) p
PIVOT
(
MAX(myId)
FOR ColName IN
( '+
@cols +' )
) AS pvt
'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: Perhaps overly pedantic, but you should use `QUOTENAME` to escape object names, not just `'[' + Col + ']'`, also I am sure it will be optimised away, but `TOP 100 PERCENT` is redundant, you are allowed to use `ORDER BY` in a subquery where `FOR XML` is used.

Comment: @GarethD, thanks for the suggestion, removed top 100 percent.