# Convert multiple rows into one with coma as separator

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I issue `SELECT ID FROM TestAhmet` I get this result:

```
1
3
5
2
4
```

but what I really need is one row with all the values separated by comma, like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

How do I do this?

ps: I cant do this : [Convert multiple rows into one with comma as separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator)

Comment: stuff is the simplest way to do it, why can't use use that?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select stuff((select ',' + cast(id as varchar(8000))
              from TestAhmet
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') as users
```

This is a variation on the string aggregation logic often used in SQL Server.  But, without a `group by`, you probably won't find many examples on the web.

Comment: Sorry. It was "ID" not "username.

Answer (score 1):

If id is numeric column then do like this

```
select stuff((select ',' +Convert(varchar(50),id)
              from TestAhmet
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') as users
```

Comment: It it is help out then given right mark and vote