# Sybase: How do I concatenate rows in sybase column

Tags: sql, t-sql, concatenation, sybase

I have a table with ID and Dept.

Table is

```
id  dept    salary  date
1   30      2000    8/25/2015 12:06:54.870 PM
2   20      5500    7/12/2015 12:06:54.870 PM
3   30      6700    11/21/2013 12:06:54.870 PM
4   30      8900    4/16/2009 12:06:54.870 PM
5   30      9900    6/29/2014 12:06:54.870 PM
6   10      1120    7/3/2015 12:06:54.870 PM
7   20      8900    4/13/2013 12:06:54.870 PM
8   10      2400    7/23/2015 12:06:54.870 PM
9   30      2600    8/21/2015 12:06:54.870 PM
10  10      2999    8/3/2015 12:06:54.870 PM
```

Just need the output like this

```
Dept  ID
30     1,3,4,5,9
```

Comment: Hello Nigel welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is this concatenation or is it more of a pivot.

Comment: should work just like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1785923/215752

Comment: @hogan Q: `Stuff`   and `XML Path` are generic tsql? because this questions say sybase.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - xml support and replace support exist in all modern db platforms.  I don't know the details of sybase, so I didn't give an answer instead I made a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way I know. Please do post if anyone knows a better solution:

I have named your table `sal`

```
DECLARE @id     INT
        , @max  INT
        , @dep  INT
        , @all  VARCHAR(255)

SELECT  @id = 1
        , @max = MAX(id)
FROM    sal

SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM sal

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN

    SELECT  @dep = dept
    FROM    #tmp
    WHERE   id = @id

    IF @dep IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @id = @id + 1

        IF @id > @max
            BREAK
        ELSE
            CONTINUE
    END

    UPDATE  #tmp
    SET     @all = @all + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, id) 
    WHERE   dept = @dep

    --remove last comma
    select  @all = RIGHT(@all, LEN(@all)-1)

    DELETE  #tmp
    WHERE   dept = @dep

    -- selecting the output. insert into table if you want
    SELECT  @dep, @all

    SELECT  @dep   = NULL
            , @all = NULL

    SELECT  @id = @id + 1

    IF @id > @max
        BREAK

    -- fail safe
    IF @id > 100
        BREAK
END

drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit simpler solution for those who want this to work for particular query:

```
DECLARE @res_csv  VARCHAR(10000)
BEGIN
    SELECT SomeIntField INTO #tmp FROM YourTblName WHERE 1=1 -- a hardcoded query
    UPDATE  #tmp
    SET     @res_csv = @res_csv + case when @res_csv is not NULL then ',' end + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SomeIntField) 
    drop table #tmp
    print @res_csv
END
```

Answer (score -3):

Depending on the size of your table, this query might not be ideal. But it worked for me when I tried it, assuming `TableName` is the name of your table:

```
SELECT dept, LIST(id, ',' ORDER BY dept) AS ID_List 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY dept;
```

Here's a detailed explanation:

- `SELECT dept`: This selects the department column from the table.
- `LIST(id, ',' ORDER BY dept) AS ID_List`: This function concatenates the IDs into a comma-separated list within each department group. The ORDER BY dept ensures that the IDs are sorted within each department.
- `FROM TableName`: Specifies the table from which data is being retrieved.
- `GROUP BY dept`: Groups the results by department, so each row represents a unique department along with its corresponding concatenated list of IDs.