# Execute Dynamic Query in a Loop in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, parallel-data-warehouse

I am trying to execute a dynamic query inside a while loop in SQL/PDW. This query will give me the max/min dates and also the distinct count of dates from a Fact table. I need to execute this for all schemas in my database (all schemas have the same table structure). The query that I am trying to execute is given below:

```
DECLARE @intCNT INT
SET @intCNT = 1
DECLARE @strSQL1 VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @strSQL2 VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @strSQL3 VARCHAR(100)


SET @strSQL1 = 'SELECT MAX(FT_DT) AS MAX_DT, 
                    MIN(FT_DT) AS MIN_DT,  
                    COUNT(DISTINCT FT_DT) AS DT_CNT 
                FROM '

SET @strSQL2 = CONCAT('(SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA
                        FROM 
                            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA) AS ROW_NUM, 
                                TABLE_SCHEMA
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                            WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''FT_TBL''
                                AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE ''F%'')T
                        WHERE ROW_NUM = ',@intCNT,')' )

SET @strSQL3 = '.FT_TBL'

EXEC (@strSQL1 + @strSQL2 + @strSQL3)
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Is it something to do with syntax? I'd like to get this working on my PDW instance. I tried in SQL Server too, but get the same error

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with the third part, you need to execute strSQL2 and then add it as table name to strSQL1 which would make your query as select * from "name generated from subquery result".

Comment: An important tool in working with dynamic sql is the PRINT statement.   PRINT the sql string(s) that you are trying to execute, and usually the syntax errors will be obvious.

Comment: What I need is "select ---- from <schema_name>.FT_TBL" for all schemas. I need to have the complete result-set saved in a table at the end of the execution.

Comment: `strSQL2` should not be a dynamic query. if you run it and concat `strSQL1` with `TABLE_SCHEMA` you will finally obtain full script with all tables. After a single run of `strSQL2`.

Comment: without row_number and @intcnt of course. which will be useless in this case.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, thanks for your reply. I may be overlooking something very obvious here, but do you mind showing how this can be done for all schemas without a loop and counter?

Comment: check out `select` in answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be replaced with a cursor with the following query to enable you to select for each schema

```
DECLARE @Schema_Name VarChar

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FT_TBL'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'F%'

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Schema_Name 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    --Do something with Id here
    execute CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT MAX(FT_DT) AS MAX_DT, 
                MIN(FT_DT) AS MIN_DT,  
                COUNT(DISTINCT FT_DT) AS DT_CNT 
            FROM ',@Schema_Name),'FT_TBL')
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Schema_Name
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'm on a Parallel data warehouse and cursors are not supported in it :(

Comment: Though i hope it can be useful for you even if only as a basis for knowing what to look for.

Comment: I found that in parallel you must use the table as a queue instead of cursor http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Answer (score 0):

what you are actually trying to excecute is:

```
SELECT MAX(FT_DT) AS MAX_DT, 
                    MIN(FT_DT) AS MIN_DT,  
                    COUNT(DISTINCT FT_DT) AS DT_CNT 
                FROM 
(SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA
                        FROM 
                            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA) AS ROW_NUM, 
                                TABLE_SCHEMA
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FT_TBL'
                                AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'F%')T
                        WHERE ROW_NUM = 1)
.FT_TBL
```

the .FT_TBL from @strSQL3 destroy your query. maybe it should be

```
set @strSQL3 = ' FT_TBL'
```

Comment: what parse error?, if it's the '' i fixed it, but i cant really test it

Comment: Thanks for that. Should I be using a dynamic sql here? When I executed your select statement (without any variables), I get:
Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parse error at line: 14, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: the  statement i have written is what you are executing, its not for you to execute. below i have written how to correct this, remove the '.' from your query