# Interbase SQL Select Group By Records into one row with commas

Tags: sql, select, group-by, interbase

I have a simple Interbase SQL Select Group By query:

```
Select STRINGNAME from STRINGLIST
Group by STRINGNAME
```

This query returns this result:

```
STRINGNAME
FirstString
SecondString
ThirdString
```

and etc.

I would like to have my query return one row that does this in any order:

```
FirstString,SecondString,ThirdString
```

or inverted

```
ThirdString,SecondString,FirstString
```

How is it possible to do it? I was thinking of a procedure but maybe there is another more simple way?

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator

Comment: please check this answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator

Comment: @YashveerSingh Sorry. I couldn't find it. Wasn't searching by keyword "concatenate".

Comment: Guys none of those work.. I think that's all for mySQL and MS SQL and not Interbase SQL or Firebird SQL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer myself. Thanks.

Firebird and Interbase have a LIST() aggregate function which does just what I need:

```
SELECT LIST(DISTINCT STRINGNAME, ',')
FROM STRINGLIST
```

This works perfectly for Interbase SQL and Firebird SQL

Answer (score 0):

using temp variable you can do this:-

```
declare @tmp varchar(max)
SET @tmp = ''
select @tmp = @tmp + STRINGNAME + ', ' from STRINGLIST Group by STRINGNAME
select @tmp
```