# T-SQL Create Comma Separated Array While Keeping Parent Category Information Intact

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Say I have a table with ProductID and OrderNumber. There are multiple products each with multiple orders.

What I'm trying to do is turn:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| ProductID | OrderNumber |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |           1 |
|         1 |           2 |
|         1 |           3 |
|         2 |           4 |
|         2 |           5 |
|         3 |           6 |
|         3 |           7 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

into:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| ProductID | OrderNumber |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |     1, 2, 3 |
|         2 |        4, 5 |
|         3 |        6, 7 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

It's easy enough to create a comma separated list of all the order numbers like shown here: [Convert multiple rows into one with comma as separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator).

What I have not been able to figure out is how to create the array from rows while still keeping the ProductID information intact.

Comment: If I understand correctly (a sample of what you are looking for would help), a dynamic pivot might be what you want. Add a sample of the array output you desire. I might be able to answer.

Comment: Aren't both of those in the post above? That first output is the table currently and the second is the array output desired.

Comment: I see... I thought the author had that already and wanted to make a different array.

Comment: You can do this with a dynamic PIVOT.

Comment: This question has been asked dozens of times

Comment: @n8 I apologize if this has been asked & answered previously. I did search prior to posting and found the linked article but had not seen a question specifically about keeping categories intact when creating the array.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to learn how to phrase a question.

Comment: In any case, it's good you have an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U need to use like below-

```
SELECT b.ProductID 
    , STUFF 
        ((
        SELECT CONCAT(', ' , a.OrderNumber)
        FROM PO a
        WHERE ( a.ProductID = b.ProductID )
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) ,1,2,'') 
        AS OrderNumber
FROM PO b
GROUP BY b.ProductID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ProductID   OrderNumber
----------- -------------------
1           1, 2, 3
2           4, 5
3           6, 7

(3 rows affected)
```

For more details pls refer -

https://msbiskills.com/2017/12/25/sql-puzzle-dynamic-pivot-puzzle/

or

https://msbiskills.com/2015/03/25/t-sql-query-group-by-xml-path-puzzle/