# How to resolve comma separated values in a set based manner?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a main table, which contains comma separated codes for each id:

`create table main (id int, codes nvarchar(3))`

```
id  codes
1   HIR, RES, NAS
2   TA1, WQ9, PLM
```

And a lookup table which describes what those codes mean:

`create table lookup (code nvarchar(3), description nvarchar(100))`

```
code  description
HIR   High Rise
NAS   Mobile Home
PLM   Proposed Attached
...
```

I want to select from the main table and replace the comma separated list of codes with a comma separated lists of corresponding descriptions:

```
id  codes
1   High Rise, Residential, Mobile Home
```

I figured out how to loop through each row, break apart the CSV, query each manually, build the string back and produce what I want.

However, is there a way to do it in a set based manner (and faster)?

Comment: Why you're storing comma delimited strings in the first place? The real problem here is the design.

Comment: Wow, comma separated values ...

Comment: Is there a limit on how many codes can be in the codes column?

Comment: [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: @Sami I am just a consumer of this data.  Didn't design it.  Nor can I change it.

Comment: @avery_larry The most I've seen is 3 codes.

Comment: @AngryHacker could you use SQL Server 2017?

Comment: @forpas Actually yes, I assumed the box was 2016, but it's 2017.  I'll fix the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can use SQL Server 2017 there is [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select m.id, string_agg(l.description, ', ') within group (order by charindex(l.code, m.codes)) codes
from main m inner join lookup l
on concat(',', replace(m.codes, ', ', ','), ',') like concat('%', l.code, '%')
group by m.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=692ecc57e1ff6e216b43a3f98e2e8454).
Results:

```
> id | codes                              
> -: | :----------------------------------
>  1 | High Rise, Residential, Mobile Home
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on 2016, one option would be string_split, but there is not gtd of maintaining the sequence.  Perhaps this will help

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Codes = B.S
 From  Main A
 Cross Apply (
                Select S = stuff((Select ', ' +[description] 
                                   From (
                                          Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                                                ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')))
                                           From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.[codes],',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                                           Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                                         ) B1
                                    Join Lookup B2 on B1.RetVal=B2.code
                                    Order by RetSeq
                                    For XML Path (''))
                                  ,1,2,'') 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Codes
1   High Rise, Mobile Home
2   Proposed Attached
```

Note Items missing because Lookup was not complete.

Answer (score 1):

For the main table you are going to want to do a cross apply STRING_SPLIT then you can join it to your lookup table and use a stuff() with for xml

You can learn about the cross apply STRING_SPLIT (SS 2016) here:
[Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows) (other methods are listed)

You can learn on the stuff with for xml here:
[Convert multiple rows into one with comma as separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator)

Comment: That function won't guarantee the order of rows and presumably they should correspond with the codes.