# How to take multiple rows and make a comma separated list in SQL

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

I have a query I ran which is

`SELECT * FROM rpg.class_primary_abilities AS cpab
INNER JOIN rpg.abilities AS ab ON cpab.ability_id = ab.ability_id
INNER JOIN rpg.classes AS cl ON cpab.class_id = cl.class_id;`

It gives me the below output.

[image]

What I would like to know is how can I change this query in order to display everything except the first `class_id` column in a comma separated list.  Essentially I would like to get an output of `class_id`and `value,value,value,value,value,value,value,value` as my two columns in the output.

I am a college student just learning SQL and have not been exposed to any possible solutions to this problem in class.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Show the results that you want.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the database, so you should say which database are you using, although the UI style appears to be SQL Server for me.

Comment: If you want SQL then look at these: [stack overflow post #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator) [stack overflow post #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please tag your database for more info.

This is one way for **Oracle** where Ihave used a concatenate sign which is `||` to concatenate(put two strings together in one) and between them I have also concatenated a comma `,`. You can also see that I have used double quotes for the column named `desc`. I did it because it is not a good practice to call your columns with keywords and word `desc` is used for example when you order by some column(at the end of the query) you can order by that column ascending then you use `asc` or descending when you can use `desc`. Also in both examples I used keyword `as` to give a name to this concatenated column.

```
SELECT class_id, cpab.ability_id || ',' || 
                 ab.ability_id  || ',' || 
                 ab.name || ',' || 
                 class_id || ',' ||  
                 cpab.name || ',' ||  
                 hit_die || ',' || 
                 "desc" || ',' || 
                 isPlayable as values
FROM rpg.class_primary_abilities AS cpab
INNER JOIN rpg.abilities AS ab ON cpab.ability_id = ab.ability_id
INNER JOIN rpg.classes AS cl ON cpab.class_id = cl.class_id;
```

This is another for **MYSQL** where I have used `concat` to concatenate column values and I have used different single quotes for `desc` column.:

```
SELECT class_id, concat(cpab.ability_id, ',' , 
                        ab.ability_id, ',' ,
                        ab.name, ',' , 
                        class_id, ',' , 
                        cpab.name, ',' , 
                        hit_die, ',' , 
                        `desc`, ',' , 
                        isPlayable) as values
FROM rpg.class_primary_abilities AS cpab
INNER JOIN rpg.abilities AS ab ON cpab.ability_id = ab.ability_id
INNER JOIN rpg.classes AS cl ON cpab.class_id = cl.class_id;
```

In both examples you have columns with same name from different tables and theer you will have to use aliases when calling them in your select clause like I have did in my example: `cpab.ability_id` and `ab.ability_id` but please note that  I do not know if they are from cpab and ab tables.

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support a function such as `string_agg()` or `listagg()` that does what you want:

```
SELECT cl.class_id,
       STRING_AGG(ability_id, ',') as ability_ids,
       . . . 
FROM rpg.class_primary_abilities cpab JOIN
     rpg.abilities ab
     ON cpab.ability_id = ab.ability_id JOIN
     rpg.classes cl
     ON cpab.class_id = cl.class_id
GROUP BY cl.class_id
```