# Use Query Result as Table Name for Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which returns rows which I want to use for an update query.

This query:

```
SELECT 
   'data_'+ REPLACE(ft.uid, '-', '_') dataview_table,  
    ft.id
FROM  father_table ft
```

returns:

```
dataview_table                              id
data_A65225EB_AEE4_478B_AC86_03E5F0D92F5B   10000291
data_0234FF89_E561_4918_870A_3FFD9928E647   10000291
data_0234FF89_E561_4918_870A_3FFD9928E647   10000291
data_021F9D95_8F87_402B_A53B_5C5AE4084D9C   10000291
```

What I want to do is to use `dataview_table` and `id` as a condition on my update query, so for each row on the `father_table` it will perform this:

```
UPDATE dataview_table SET status = 5 WHERE id = id
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you can directly fetch and execute it, instead, you'll have to use the  Dynamic SQL or Query String approach. Like this

```
DECLARE @Qry VARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        Qry = 'UPDATE data_'+ REPLACE(ft.uid, '-', '_')+' SET status = 5 WHERE id = '+    CAST(ft.id AS VARCHAR(20))
        FROM  father_table ft
)
SELECT
    @Qry = STRING_AGG(Qry,';')
    FROM CTE
    
EXEC(@Qry)
```

Comment: I'm using `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4583460) - 13.0.5103.6 (X64)` and STRING_AGG doesn't seem to work. Is there any alternative for STRING_AGG on your code?

Comment: You can use XML data type. Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator