# SQL - Make a comma delimited column from other columns

Tags: sql

I am attempting to make a column in which it is a comma delimited list of other columns where the id is the same. How can I take the query I currently have, and update it to get the output that I expect?

T1

| PK |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

T2

| ID | Name | T1.PK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1 |
| 2 | Pear | 1 |
| 3 | Orange | 1 |
| 4 | Cat | 2 |
| 5 | Dog | 2 |

My hope is I can join these tables and get the following result.

| PK | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple, Pear, Orange |
| 2 | Cat, Dog |

I have a rough idea of how to accomplish this, but I do not see how to separate the list, instead I will get Apple, Pear, Orange, Cat, Dog for each row instead of them being separated. Here is the query I am currently working with.

```
select t1.PK,
stuff(
   (select distinct ', ' + Name
    from t2
    for XML PATH ("")), 1, 2, '') Name
from t1
left join t2
```

Comment: What's your RDBMS (assuming SQL server) and its version

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding the question, but do you have a `GROUP BY t1.PK` in your query? Please post the full query (including the `ON` and `GROUP BY`).

Comment: Recursive CTE, Connect By Prior, String_Agg, List_Agg, Stuff, For XML Path... just depends on RDBMS/Version and availability of these features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.PK,
stuff(
   (select ', ' + Name
    from t2
    where t2.[t1.PK] = t1.PK 
    for XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') Name
from t1
```

I answered this question about 12 years ago

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785923/215752

Answer (score 2):

In new SQL Server DB's (since SQL Server 2017), it's also possible to use `STRING_AGG` for this purpose:

```
SELECT t1.pk, STRING_AGG (t2.name,', ') AS name
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.pk = t2.[t1.pk]
GROUP BY t1.pk;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use string_agg. Thank you.